# wrong php.ini file being loading

Tags: php, apache, mamp, ini

I'm using MAMP and the changes i make in my php.ini file aren't loading. What I've read here so far has often been windows specific and just not getting me there.

The problem may have something to do with the "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" (the one I'm editing) and the "Loaded Configuration File" not being the same when checking them in phpinfo.

> Path = /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf.
>
> Loaded = /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/conf/php.ini.

The "conf" folder in the "loaded" path doesn't exist in my finder or i'd just change the php.ini there (the one it says it's loading).

**phpinfo screen shot**

[image]

I can't continue on with this project until output buffering is turned on :(

Comment: have you restart your server?

Comment: `The "conf" folder in the "loaded" path doesn't exist in my finder` - then recompile PHP with a different path or create the folder and put your php.ini in there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  Your suggestion would have fixed the problem i'm sure.  Unfortunately, i was in the wrong folder all together :( Not sure why there are so many php.ini files scattered through out my MAMP folder.